# Adverse effects from sitting for too long

Tags: back, back-pain, lower-back

I have a desk job which requires me to be seated for a wall 10 to 12 hours each day including weekends. I perform only minimum amount of physical activities and excercise each day for about half an hour or so. What adverse effects can it have on my health and on my back in the long run if I continue this practice.

What can I do to minimise its effects

I have heard of a lumbar support, does it help ??

Answer (score 1):

According to [WorkSafe Queensland](https://www.worksafe.qld.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0010/82729/factsheet-sedentary-work.pdf), the government body responsible for regulating Workplace Health and Safety in the Australian state of Queensland, increasing movement during sedentary work can help prevent the following conditions:

> Sitting less and moving more can benefit you by:
>
> - reducing the risk of musculoskeletal pain, discomfort and injury,    particularly of the lower back and neck
> - lowering the risk of developing coronary heart disease
> - lowering the risk of developing diabetes
> - reducing eye strain or fatigue as your eyes have a chance to focus    over different distances.
>
> Movement is also better for the circulatory system and digestive
> tract.

The document I linked above also includes suggestions on how you can incorporate more movement into your daily workplace routine.